# How to specify the number of threads/processes for the default dask scheduler

Tags: python, dask

Is there a way to limit the number of cores used by the default threaded scheduler (default when using dask dataframes)?

With `compute`, you can specify it by using:

```
df.compute(get=dask.threaded.get, num_workers=20)
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to set this as the default, so you don't need to specify this for each `compute` call?

The would eg be interesting in the case of a small cluster (eg of 64 cores), but which is shared with other people (without a job system), and I don't want to necessarily take up all cores when starting computations with dask.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can specify a default ThreadPool

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import dask
dask.config.set(pool=ThreadPool(20))
```

Comment: ThreadPool(20) sets the number of processes to 20. Is there a way to restrict the number of threads per process? Handling many threads in a single process can produce unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @AndiR Thats a wrong assumption. `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` is a pool of *threads*, and not the same as `multiprocessing.Pool`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool