# How call a `@guvectorize` inside a `@guvectorize` in numba?

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to call a `@guvectorize` inside a `@guvectorize` but I have an error saying :

```
Untyped global name 'regNL_nb': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numpy.ufunc'>

File "di.py", line 12:
def H2Delay_nb(S1, S2, R2):
    H1 = regNL_nb(S1, S2)
    ^
```

here is an MRE:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import guvectorize, float64, int64, njit, cuda, jit

@guvectorize(["float64[:], float64[:], float64[:]"], '(n),(n)->(n)')
def regNL_nb(S1, S2, h2):
    for i in range(len(S1)):
        h2[i] = S1[i] + S2[i]

@guvectorize(["float64[:], float64[:],  float64[:]"], '(n),(n)->(n)',nopython=True)
def H2Delay_nb(S1, S2, R2):
    H1 = regNL_nb(S1, S2)
    H2 = regNL_nb(S1, S2,)
    for i in range(len(S1)):
        R2[i] =  H1[i] + H2[i]


S1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
S2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
H2 = H2Delay_nb(S1, S2)
print(H2)
```

I don't know how do I tell to numba that the function regNL_nb is a guvectorize function.

Comment: The expected output is supposed to be `[ 4.  8. 12. 16. 20. 24. 28. 32. 36.]`, correct?

Comment: yes, it is. just four time each number

Comment: I executed your above script the way it was, except setting the parameter `nopython` to `False`, hence risking that the code will fallback to object mode - besides a warning it worked fine. `>>> print(H2)` gives the Output: `[ 4.  8. 12. 16. 20. 24. 28. 32. 36.]`.

Comment: Yes, it works like this but It is slower. The point is to keep the nopython=True mode, so the code run faster.

Comment: I know that; though if you deactivate the object mode not all values will be handled as Python objects. (see https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/glossary.html#term-object-mode)

Comment: Yes your're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is only for the case if you're fine with replacing @guvectorize with @njit, it will be totally same code, same fast, just a bit more longer syntax to use.

It is probably some issue with accepting `@guvectorize`-ed functions inside other guvectorized function in nopython mode.

But Numba accepts perfectly good just regular `@njit`-ed functions inside other njited. So you may rewrite your function to use @njit, your function signature will remain same as @guvectorize-ed for outside world. @njit version will just need extra usage of `np.empty_like(...)` + return inside function.

To remind you - all @njit-ed functions are always having nopython mode enabled, so your njited code will be same fast as guvectorize+nopython.

Also I provide CUDA solution as second code snippet.

You may also make @njited only internal helper function, but external you probably can still have as @guvectorize-ed. Also if you want universal function (accepting any inputs) just remove signature `'f8[:](f8[:], f8[:])'` from njited definition, signature will be auto-resolved on call.

Final code looks like this:

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow65353407#main.py)

```
import numpy as np
from numba import guvectorize, float64, int64, njit, cuda, jit

@njit('f8[:](f8[:], f8[:])', cache = True)
def regNL_nb(S1, S2):
    h2 = np.empty_like(S1)
    for i in range(len(S1)):
        h2[i] = S1[i] + S2[i]
    return h2
        
@njit('f8[:](f8[:], f8[:])', cache = True)
def H2Delay_nb(S1, S2):
    H1 = regNL_nb(S1, S2)
    H2 = regNL_nb(S1, S2)
    R2 = np.empty_like(H1)
    for i in range(len(S1)):
        R2[i] =  H1[i] + H2[i]
    return R2

S1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], dtype = np.float64)
S2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], dtype = np.float64)
H2 = H2Delay_nb(S1, S2)
print(H2)
```

Output:

```
[ 4.  8. 12. 16. 20. 24. 28. 32. 36.]
```

CUDA variant of same code, it needs extra functions-wrappers if you want to automatically create and return resulting array, because CUDA-code function doesn't allow to have return value:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import guvectorize, float64, int64, njit, cuda, jit

@cuda.jit('void(f8[:], f8[:], f8[:])', cache = True)
def regNL_nb_cu(S1, S2, h2):
    for i in range(len(S1)):
        h2[i] = S1[i] + S2[i]
        
@njit('f8[:](f8[:], f8[:])', cache = True)
def regNL_nb(S1, S2):
    h2 = np.empty_like(S1)
    regNL_nb_cu(S1, S2, h2)
    return h2
        
@cuda.jit('void(f8[:], f8[:], f8[:])', cache = True)
def H2Delay_nb_cu(S1, S2, R2):
    H1 = regNL_nb(S1, S2)
    H2 = regNL_nb(S1, S2)
    for i in range(len(S1)):
        R2[i] =  H1[i] + H2[i]
        
@njit('f8[:](f8[:], f8[:])', cache = True)
def H2Delay_nb(S1, S2):
    R2 = np.empty_like(S1)
    H2Delay_nb_cu(S1, S2, R2)
    return R2

S1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], dtype = np.float64)
S2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], dtype = np.float64)
H2 = H2Delay_nb(S1, S2)
print(H2)
```

Comment: This isn't equivalent — if `S1` & `S2` have more dimensions, then `njit` doesn't broadcast. Try running it on `S2 = S1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]], dtype = np.float64)`...

Answer (score 1):

```
@guvectorize(["float64[:], float64[:],  float64[:]"], '(n),(n)->(n)',nopython=True)
def H2Delay_nb(S1, S2, R2):
    H1 = regNL_nb(S1, S2)
    H2 = regNL_nb(S1, S2,)
    for i in range(len(S1)):
        R2[i] =  H1[i] + H2[i]
```

By using the parameter `nopython = True` you deactivate the object mode and hence Numba isn't able to handle all values as Python objects (refer to: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/glossary.html#term-object-mode)

In general are Panda, Numba or other function calls not possible if you use `nopython = True`. There is only a limited amount of libraries you can use with Numba Jit (in `nopython`).
The full list can be found here: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html.

So what you are trying to do isn't possible, except of disabling `nopython`, that is:

```
@guvectorize(["float64[:], float64[:],  float64[:]"], '(n),(n)->(n)',nopython=False)
    def H2Delay_nb(S1, S2, R2):
        H1 = regNL_nb(S1, S2)
        H2 = regNL_nb(S1, S2,)
        for i in range(len(S1)):
            R2[i] =  H1[i] + H2[i]
```

Going with this approach the programme outputs the correct value, i.e. `[ 4.  8. 12. 16. 20. 24. 28. 32. 36.]` for `H2`.

I also found another StackOverflow question dealing with a familiar issue: [numba - TypingError: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744686/numba-typingerror-cannot-determine-numba-type-of-class-builtin-function-or). Credits where credit is due: [Kevin K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6078026/kevin-k) suggested in the mentioned thread that you shall use **'simpler' data types** - which are most often found in CPython. Other than that, and I fully agree with him on this point, I wouldn't be aware of any possible solution in `nopython` mode activated.

---

**Sources:**

- [numba - TypingError: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744686/numba-typingerror-cannot-determine-numba-type-of-class-builtin-function-or)
- https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/glossary.html
- https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/proposals/type-inference.html
- https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html
- https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4627