# Problem by dictionaries to use numba njit parallelization to accelerate the code

Tags: performance, optimization, parallel-processing, numba, jit

I have written a code and try to use numba for accelerating the code. The main goal of the code is to group some values based on a condition. In this regard, `iter_` is used for converging the code to satisfy the condition. I prepared a small case below to reproduce the sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

rng = np.random.default_rng(85)

# --------------------------------------- small data volume ---------------------------------------
# values_ = {'R0': np.array([0.01090976, 0.01069902, 0.00724112, 0.0068463 , 0.01135723, 0.00990762,
#                                        0.01090976, 0.01069902, 0.00724112, 0.0068463 , 0.01135723]),
#            'R1': np.array([0.01836379, 0.01900166, 0.01864162, 0.0182823 , 0.01840322, 0.01653088,
#                                        0.01900166, 0.01864162, 0.0182823 , 0.01840322, 0.01653088]),
#            'R2': np.array([0.02430913, 0.02239156, 0.02225379, 0.02093393, 0.02408692, 0.02110411,
#                                        0.02239156, 0.02225379, 0.02093393, 0.02408692, 0.02110411])}
#
# params = {'R0': [3, 0.9490579204466154, 1825, 7.070272000000002e-05],
#           'R1': [0, 0.9729203826820172, 167 , 7.070272000000002e-05],
#           'R2': [1, 0.6031363088057902, 1316, 8.007296000000003e-05]}
#
# Sno, dec_, upd_ = 2, 100, 200
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ----------------------------- UPDATED (medium and large data volumes) ---------------------------
# values_ = np.load("values_med.npy", allow_pickle=True)[()]
# params = np.load("params_med.npy", allow_pickle=True)[()]
values_ = np.load("values_large.npy", allow_pickle=True)[()]
params = np.load("params_large.npy", allow_pickle=True)[()]

Sno, dec_, upd_ = 2000, 1000, 200
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# values_ = [*values_.values()]
# params = [*params.values()]


# @nb.jit(forceobj=True)
# def test(values_, params, Sno, dec_, upd_):

final_dict = {}
for i, j in enumerate(values_.keys()):
    Rand_vals = []
    goal_sum = params[j][1] * params[j][3]
    tel = goal_sum / dec_ * 10
    if params[j][0] != 0:
        for k in range(Sno):
            final_sum = 0.0
            iter_ = 0
            t = 1
            while not np.allclose(goal_sum, final_sum, atol=tel):
                iter_ += 1
                vals_group = rng.choice(values_[j], size=params[j][0], replace=False)
                # final_sum = 0.0016 * np.sum(vals_group)  # -----> For small data volume
                final_sum = np.sum(vals_group ** 3)        # -----> UPDATED For med or large data volume
                if iter_ == upd_:
                    t += 1
                    tel = t * tel
            values_[j] = np.delete(values_[j], np.where(np.in1d(values_[j], vals_group)))
            Rand_vals.append(vals_group)
    else:
        Rand_vals = [np.array([])] * Sno
    final_dict["R" + str(i)] = Rand_vals

#    return final_dict


# test(values_, params, Sno, dec_, upd_)
```

At first, for applying numba on this code `@nb.jit` was used (`forceobj=True` is used for avoiding warnings and …), which will have adverse effect on the performance. `nopython` is checked, too, with `@nb.njit` which get the following error due to [not supporting](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7503) (as mentioned in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078628/using-dictionaries-with-numba-njit-function), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744686/numba-typingerror-cannot-determine-numba-type-of-class-builtin-function-or)) **dictionary type** of the inputs:

> cannot determine Numba type of <class 'dict'>

I don't know if (how) it could be handled by `Dict` from `numba.typed` (by converting created python dictionaries to numba Dict) or if converting the *dictionaries* to *lists of arrays* have any advantage. I think, parallelization may be possible if some code lines e.g. `Rand_vals.append(vals_group)` or *else section* or … be taken or be modified out of the function to get the same results as before, but I don't have any idea how to do so.

I will be grateful for helping utilize numba on this code. **`numba parallelization` will be the most desired (probably the best applicable method in terms of performance) solution if it could**.

---

### Data:

- medium data volume: [values_med](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lIeYkbmw6Mjeb6xHY25D5UFuOvBvg9QC/view?usp=sharing), [params_med](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GjYK13KjyJGab4eyX9V8MRILv_K8S6oa/view?usp=sharing)
- large data volume: [values_large](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GoQaeYoM5WwBL4jM5ALGw8FN7lyiTLZG/view?usp=sharing), [params_large](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13TsB4mGGpchWd-32POIfHfLzGbQB4SCz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Note that `vals_group` is undefined if the while condition is false the first time.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, Good point. Also, I think it will never be happened on my data. I will consider it and check, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code can be converted to Numba but it is not straightforward.

First of all, the dictionary and list type must be defined since Numba **`njit` functions cannot directly operate on reflected lists** (aka. pure-python lists). This is a bit tedious to do in Numba and the resulting code is a bit verbose:

```py
String = nb.types.unicode_type
ValueArray = nb.float64[::1]
ValueDict = nb.types.DictType(String, ValueArray)
ParamDictValue = nb.types.Tuple([nb.int_, nb.float64, nb.int_, nb.float64])
ParamDict = nb.types.DictType(String, ParamDictValue)
FinalDictValue = nb.types.ListType(ValueArray)
FinalDict = nb.types.DictType(String, FinalDictValue)
```

Then you need to convert the input dictionaries:

```py
nbValues = nb.typed.typeddict.Dict.empty(String, ValueArray)
for key,value in values_.items():
    nbValues[key] = value.copy()

nbParams = nb.typed.typeddict.Dict.empty(String, ParamDictValue)
for key,value in params.items():
    nbParams[key] = (nb.int_(value[0]), nb.float64(value[1]), nb.int_(value[2]), nb.float64(value[3]))
```

Then, you need to write the core function. `np.allclose` and `np.isin` are not implemented in Numba so they should be reimplemented manually. But the main point is that Numba does not support the `rng` Numpy object. I think it will certainly not support it any time soon. Note that Numba has an random numbers implementation that try to mimic the behavior of Numpy but the management of the seed is a bit different. Note also that results should be the same with the `np.random.xxx` Numpy functions if the seed is set to the same value (Numpy and Numba have different seed variables that are not synchronized).

```py
@nb.njit(FinalDict(ValueDict, ParamDict, nb.int_, nb.int_, nb.int_))
def nbTest(values_, params, Sno, dec_, upd_):
    final_dict = nb.typed.Dict.empty(String, FinalDictValue)
    for i, j in enumerate(values_.keys()):
        Rand_vals = nb.typed.List.empty_list(ValueArray)
        goal_sum = params[j][1] * params[j][3]
        tel = goal_sum / dec_ * 10
        if params[j][0] != 0:
            for k in range(Sno):
                final_sum = 0.0
                iter_ = 0
                t = 1

                vals_group = np.empty(0, dtype=nb.float64)

                while np.abs(goal_sum - final_sum) > (1e-05 * np.abs(final_sum) + tel):
                    iter_ += 1
                    vals_group = np.random.choice(values_[j], size=params[j][0], replace=False)
                    final_sum = 0.0016 * np.sum(vals_group)
                    # final_sum = 0.0016 * np.sum(vals_group)  # (for small data volume)
                    final_sum = np.sum(vals_group ** 3)        # (for med or large data volume)
                    if iter_ == upd_:
                        t += 1
                        tel = t * tel

                # Perform an in-place deletion
                vals, gr = values_[j], vals_group
                cur = 0
                for l in range(vals.size):
                    found = False
                    for m in range(gr.size):
                        found |= vals[l] == gr[m]
                    if not found:
                        # Keep the value (delete it otherwise)
                        vals[cur] = vals[l]
                        cur += 1
                values_[j] = vals[:cur]

                Rand_vals.append(vals_group)
        else:
            for k in range(Sno):
                Rand_vals.append(np.empty(0, dtype=nb.float64))
        final_dict["R" + str(i)] = Rand_vals
    return final_dict
```

Note that the replacement implementation of `np.isin` is quite naive but it works pretty well in practice on your input example.

The function can be called using the following way:

```py
nbFinalDict = nbTest(nbValues, nbParams, Sno, dec_, upd_)
```

Finally, the dictionary should be converted back to basic Python objects:

```py
finalDict = dict()
for key,value in nbFinalDict.items():
    finalDict[key] = list(value)
```

This implementation is fast for small inputs but not large ones since **`np.random.choice` takes almost all the time** (>96%). The thing is this function is *clearly not optimal* when the number of requested item is small (which is your case). Indeed, it surprisingly runs in linear time of the input array and not in linear time of the number of requested items.

---

### Further Optimizations

The algorithm can be completely rewritten to extract only 12 random items and discard them from the main currant array in a much more efficient way. The idea is to swap `n` items (small target sample) at the end of the array with other items at random locations, then check the sum, repeat this process until a condition is fulfilled, and finally extract the view to the last `n` items before resizing the view so to discard the last items. All of this can be done in `O(n)` time rather than `O(m)` time where `m` is the size of the main current array with `n << m` (eg. 12 VS 20_000). It can also be compute without any expensive allocation. Here is the resulting code:

```py
@nb.njit(nb.void(ValueArray, nb.int_, nb.int_))
def swap(arr, i, j):
    arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]

@nb.njit(FinalDict(ValueDict, ParamDict, nb.int_, nb.int_, nb.int_))
def nbTest(values_, params, Sno, dec_, upd_):
    final_dict = nb.typed.Dict.empty(String, FinalDictValue)
    for i, j in enumerate(values_.keys()):
        Rand_vals = nb.typed.List.empty_list(ValueArray)
        goal_sum = params[j][1] * params[j][3]
        tel = goal_sum / dec_ * 10
        values = values_[j]
        n = params[j][0]

        if n != 0:
            for k in range(Sno):
                final_sum = 0.0
                iter_ = 0
                t = 1

                m = values.size
                assert n <= m
                group = values[-n:]

                while np.abs(goal_sum - final_sum) > (1e-05 * np.abs(final_sum) + tel):
                    iter_ += 1

                    # Swap the group view with other random items
                    for pos in range(m - n, m):
                        swap(values, pos, np.random.randint(0, m))

                    # For small data volume:
                    # final_sum = 0.0016 * np.sum(group)

                    # For med/large data volume
                    final_sum = 0.0
                    for v in group:
                        final_sum += v ** 3

                    if iter_ == upd_:
                        t += 1
                        tel *= t

                assert iter_ > 0
                values = values[:m-n]
                Rand_vals.append(group)
        else:
            for k in range(Sno):
                Rand_vals.append(np.empty(0, dtype=nb.float64))
        final_dict["R" + str(i)] = Rand_vals
    return final_dict
```

In addition to being faster, this implementation as the benefit of being also simpler. Results looks quite similar to the previous implementation despite the randomness make the check of the results tricky (especially since this function does not use the same method to choose the random sample). Note that this implementation does not remove items in `values` that are in `group` as opposed to the previous one (this is probably not wanted though).

---

### Benchmark

Here are the results of the last implementation on my machine (compilation and conversion timings excluded):

```
Provided small input (embedded in the question):
 - Initial code:   42.71 ms
 - Numba code:      0.11 ms

Medium input:
 - Initial code:   3481 ms
 - Numba code:       11 ms

Large input:
 - Initial code:   6728 ms
 - Numba code:       20 ms
```

Note that the conversion time takes about the same time than the computation.

This last implementation is **316~388 times faster** than the initial code on small inputs.

---

### Notes

Note that the compilation time takes few seconds due to the dict and lists types.

Note that while it may be possible to parallelise the implementation, only the most encompassing loop can be parallelised. The thing is there is only few items to compute and the time is already quite small (not the best case for multi-threading). <-- Additionally, the creation of many temporary arrays (created by `rng.choice`) will certainly cause the parallel loop not to scale well anyway. --> Additionally, the list/dict cannot be written from multiple threads safely so one need to use Numpy arrays in the whole function to be able to do that (or add additional conversion that are already expensive). Moreover, Numba parallelism tends to increase significantly the compilation time which is already significant. Finally, the result will be less deterministic since each Numba thread has its own random number generator seed and the items computed by the threads cannot be predicted with `prange` (dependent of the parallel runtime chosen on the target platform). Note that in Numpy there is one global seed by default used by usual random functions (deprecated way) and RNG objects have their own seed (new preferred way).

Comment: Thanks for explanations, It raised [TypeError(msg)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UwD8HSVI48LdbDGqKb6foW73hgQTsL9r/view?usp=sharing). Is it possible to use equivalent numba random generators (as you said *Numba have its own way to generate random numbers (that can be used safely in parallel loops)*) instead of `rng.choice` or `np.random.choice` (with `replace=False`; also, seed to reproduce); If so, why you didn't use that instead of `np.random.choice`. The main objective is to create groups in this manner that satisfy the specified condition; So, not the same but similar act.

Comment: What is the purpose of `if not found` section? Why might the above for-loop could not find it?

Unfortunately, My created large data volume is not working on this code yet (This code is a short example which is changed to differ from the main code, to be placed here). I will try to make it workable. In my previous run on a large data, it takes around 2 hours, so some seconds for compilation will be very satisfying. There will be maximum number of 10 to 15 number of loops (R0-R10 or R15) in the main code for the most outer loop for parallelization.

Comment: I have added a bigger data volumes to test performance for parallelization or …, and changed `final_sum = 0.0016 * np.sum(vals_group)` to `final_sum = np.sum(vals_group ** 3)`; this formula is working on both *med* and *larger*. Runtime can be increased by increasing `dec_` magnitude e.g. from `100` to `100000` or more, if needed for evaluations.

Comment: I am a little confused by *Numba have its own way to generate random numbers (that can be used safely in parallel loops)*. Did you mean numba controls `np.random.choice` to be faster and safer for parallel loops with its own capabilities or there are numba random modules to use instead of `np.random.choice` that you didn't use in this solution?

Comment: The typing error is certainly due to a int64/int32 incompatibility. Such error are really cumbersome as `nb.int_` changes regarding the platform but also some functions return int64 while some others return an int32 (and AFAIK this can change and not match with `nb.int_` on some platforms)... I guess this is because you certainly use Linux while I used Windows for the tests. Besides this, note that this code use recent experimental features of Numba (eg. dicts) so you need a pretty recent version of Numba.

Comment: For random numbers, AFAIK there are one global seed and basic global Numpy functions but no generator object with its own seed. Note that Numpy have a global seed shared amongst thread while Numba use a kind of thread-local RNG seeds. I do not think it is faster but it better support multi-threaded codes. For the `if not found`, the idea is to do the same thing as `np.delete(values_[j], np.where(np.in1d(values_[j], vals_group)))` but using a more efficient approach (with an in-place partitioning + a view).

Comment: I tried to clarify a bit this part. My point is that I think this is very tricky (if even possible) to try to reproduce the same random values between a parallel Numba code and a Numpy one. Non reproducibility results in a code harder to check and thus to more possible bugs (not to mention that parallel codes tends to also have more bugs -- particularly more sneaky ones).  Besides this, for the error, It seems the object you are passing are PyObject while they must be typed-dicts.

Comment: I have tested the code in both [COLAB](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SYWjTdEwbtw4q-oQ5VxfxWsVHRIpfnv2?usp=sharing) and my windows (10 enterprise, x64, CPU i5 @2.8GHz, Ram 16Gb), and both show the error. I couldn't test it yet. How to find what to do (*perhaps it is better to try on colab which get error as on my windows*)? I have tested on Numba ver `0.53.1` and `0.55.1` (updated). I don't think that it be related to **experimental** new features of Numba!? is it? This answer is full of notes for me, and also is challenging, so it may be better to move this discussion to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243924/discussion-between-ali-sh-and-jerome-richard).