# python numba error when passing a np.random.Generator object to a njit-decorated function

Tags: python, numpy, numba, random-seed

I have a module that looks as following:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def random_numba_function(rng):
    print(rng.choice([0,1,2]))

seed = 1
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
random_numba_function(rng)
```

This returns the error message for the decorated function `random_numba_function`:

```
argument 0: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numpy.random._generator.Generator'>
```

The [documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.22.1/reference/numpysupported.html#random) states that the `numpy.random.seed` function is supported, but the `np.random.default_rng` function is not listed as a supported function which probably means that you cannot pass a random number generator this way.

In my particular situation, I also have a conditional inside of the decorated function which decides whether or not to "draw" a number from the random number generator. This means that I can't just calculate the index of the random choice ahead of time and pass it to the function as an integer, since I only know if I am going to be using it once I am inside of the function. Is there an efficient way to substitute the way random seed numbers are generated with numba?

Comment: "The documentation states that numpy.random.seed objects are supported" - that's not what the documentation means. There is no such thing as a "numpy.random.seed object". `numpy.random.seed` is a function that, in normal code, would seed the module-level RNG used for the (legacy API) module-level `numpy.random` random number generation functions. In Numba code, it instead seeds a Numba-specific RNG, which Numba will use if you try to call `numpy.random` functions from Numba code.

Comment: AFAIK, Numba does not support the rng Numpy object. I think it will certainly not support it any time soon. [There is a good discussion on my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71865340/13394817). Hope be useful.

Comment: A possible solution is to use `np.random.choice` directly or use [`objmode`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/withobjmode.html) with the caveats mentioned in the docs in mind.