# Parallelize pandas dataframe.apply function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing

My use case is that I want to `apply` a function to each row of `pandas` `dataframe`. The function to be applied has some additional parameters than the row data itself and it does return more than one value. My current implementation is below

```
def func_apply(x, p1, p2, p3):
    return x.name, p1, p2, p3
```

In `func_apply` parameters are returned back just to manifest the situation. In actual scenario, this function takes `networkx` graph as input and reads transformations from the `dataframe` row and performs those transformations on the graph. So, the `func_apply` is not as simple as it looks in this example. Below is the `dataframe`

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
data['col1'] = np.random.normal(size = 15000)
data['col2'] = np.random.normal(size = 15000)
```

New columns are added to the `dataframe` with the following line

```
data[['col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']] = data.apply(func_apply,axis=1, result_type='expand', p1='a', p2='b', p3 = 'c')
```

Although it works but with the graph and transformation thing that actual `func_apply` performs, it takes a long time to execute. How can I speed it up by doing this in parallel?
I have looked at some options like `dask` and `swifter` but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545110/how-do-you-parallelize-apply-on-pandas-dataframes-making-use-of-all-cores-on-o) suggests that these tools will not work effectively on string columns. I also tried using `multiprocessing` and `Pool` but I have no idea how to pass the extra arguments to the `func_apply` and how to insert the returned data into new columns of the `dataframe`.

Comment: salam, is not possible to apply vectorised solutions on your code, is it only possible via a custom function?

Comment: wa-alikum-salam. yep, it's only possible via a custom function

Comment: then `Dask` seems like the winner here [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45545111/9375102) answer doesn't specifically say anything about using strings vs integers?