# Parallelize pandas function pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a huge list of data frames called df_list (with some different and some common columns) which I wish to merge into one big data frame. I have tried the following:

```
all_dfs = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Though this takes too much time on a single core. I killed the script after 48 hours. How would you parallelize this process to use all my cores or rewrite the code to make it faster

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` - is not about `parallel processing`.

The easiest way is to use third-party tools to process huge data frames. You can run computing / processing of data set on different nodes.

- You can look at [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) (similar with `pandas` interface).
- You can look at [pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#enabling-for-conversion-tofrom-pandas).

Also you can use [swifter](https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter) to runs processing on multiple cores.

There are probably some other tools... In other words, in your case it is better to run calculations in a `cluster`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: [good example pandas + dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545110/how-do-you-parallelize-apply-on-pandas-dataframes-making-use-of-all-cores-on-o/45545111#45545111)