# Convert prices with daily rate in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm currently trying to normalize a DataFrame(~600k rows) with prices (`pricevalue`) in different currencies(`pricecurrency`) so that every row has prices in EUR.

I'd like to convert them with the daily rate taken from a column `date`.

My current "solution" (using the [CurrencyConverter](https://pypi.org/project/CurrencyConverter/) package found on PyPI) looks like this:

```py
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter

c = CurrencyConverter(fallback_on_missing_rate=True,fallback_on_missing_rate_method="last_known")

def convert_currency(row):
     return c.convert(row["pricevalue"], row["pricecurrency"],row["date"])

df["converted_eur"] = df.apply(lambda x: convert_currency(x),axis=1)
```

However, this solution is taking forever to run.

Is there a faster way to accomplish that? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: does this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51669468/6660373?

Comment: Do you have the YOURCOIN>EUR daily price in another sheet or is this CurrencyConverter package getting i for you? If so, it might explain the long time to do it.

Comment: Are these current prices or historic prices? What is the range of dates that a price could be in?

Comment: @mrbTT The CurrencyConverter Package is getting the prices for me

Comment: @Pygirl Will check out the post, thank you.

Comment: @Dave the prices are historic prices. The prices are ranging from ~2008 - 2018, so i need some form of lookup of the exchange rate, which is provided by the CurrencyConverter Package mentioned.

Comment: @Dave, roughly 600.000 rows as mentioned in the post.

Comment: The issue might be that CurrencyConverter needs to get the values online, and it's API has a limited number of queries or is slow to fetch results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds strange to say this, but unfortunately you're not doing anything wrong!

The [currency interpolation code](https://github.com/alexprengere/currencyconverter/blob/1d7ecf7bb9d2521cd9170e666de36819129b5710/currency_converter/currency_converter.py#L321) is doing what you need it to do, and not much else. In your code, you're doing everything right. This means there's no thing you can quickly fix to get performance. You have a double lambda where you only need a single, but that won't make much of a difference:

i.e.

`df["converted_eur"] = df.apply(lambda x: convert_currency(x),axis=1)`

should be

`df["converted_eur"] = df.apply(convert_currency, axis=1)`

The first thing to do is to understand how long this processing will actually take by adding some UI:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

df["converted_eur"] = df.progress_apply(convert_currency, axis=1)
```

Once you know how long the job will actually take, try out these, in order:

1. Live with it.
2. Single instance parallelization, with something like [pandarallel](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel)
3. Multi instance parallelization, with something like [Dask](https://dask.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and pointing out further readings! Will definitely take a look at option 2 and 3. tqdm is btw a neat little tool i'll add to my toolbox! :)

Comment: Happy to help! Let us know what you go with in the end.