# Interpolate CubicSpline with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, interpolation, cubic

I have a dataframe with ResidMat and Price, I use scipy to find the interpolate CubicSpline. I used CubicSpline and apply to find all data on my dataset. But it's not very fast, because in this case have no more data. I will have more than a hundred data and it's very slow. Do you have an idea to do that but maybe with a matrix ?

Thank you,

```
    def add_interpolated_price(row, generic_residmat):
        from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
        residmats = row[['ResidMat']].values
        prices = row[['Price']].values
        cs = CubicSpline(residmats, prices)
        return float(cs(generic_residmat))

    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,18,38,58,83,103,128,148,32.4,32.5,33.8,33.5,32.8,32.4,32.7],[2,17,37,57,82,102,127,147,31.2,31.5,32.7,33.2,32.5,32.9,33.3]],columns = ['index','ResidMat','ResidMat','ResidMat','ResidMat','ResidMat','ResidMat','ResidMat','Price','Price','Price','Price','Price','Price','Price'],index=['2010-06-25','2010-06-28'])
    my_resimmat = 30
    df['Generic_Value'] =  df.apply(lambda row: add_interpolated_price(row, generic_residmat=my_resimmat), axis=1)
```

Comment: Tried the code and it turns out that I got a `TypeError: Cannot convert bool to numpy.ndarray`

Comment: Thank Paul, yes my bad.     df['Generic_Value'] =  df.apply(lambda row: add_interpolated_price(row, generic_residmat=my_resimmat), axis=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the profile of this code most of the time is spent in interpolating so the best thing I would suggest is going pandarallel.  [Make Pandas DataFrame apply() use all cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545110/make-pandas-dataframe-apply-use-all-cores) has the details.  My fave is this method... (outline code below)

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
from math import sin

pandarallel.initialize()

def func(x):
    return sin(x**2)

df.parallel_apply(func, axis=1)
```

but this only works on Linux and Macos, on Windows, Pandarallel will work only if the Python session is executed from Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

Comment: Hello Paul, good idea ! I will try this ! Thank you for your time