# Using apply in pandas take long time in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am trying to use apply function in data frame.

Below is the sample data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
from CoolProp.HumidAirProp import HAPropsSI

df =pd.DataFrame()
df['T'] = [23,35,55]
df ['RH'] = [50,70,35]
df['H']= df.apply(lambda x: HAPropsSI('H','T',x ['T']+273.15, 'P',101325,'R',x ['RH']/100), axis = 1)
```

The actual data frame contains 400,000 rows and 8 columns. When I apply the abovementioned function in my actual data frame, it takes long time to complete. Are there any other ways, which can enhance the computing speed?

## Updated

I tried to use the vetorization as follow:

```
df ['Enthalpy'] = np.vectorize(HAPropsSI) ('H','T',df ['T']+273.15, 'P',101325,'R',df ['RH']/100)
```

It shows the following error:

```
TypeError: Numerical inputs to HAPropsSI must be ints, floats, lists, or 1D numpy arrays.
```

The input for the function is as follow:

```
HAPropsSI('H',T',x ['T']+273.15,P',101325,'R',x ['RH']/100)
```

The first parameter, H is the parameter that I want to find.

The second para, T is the type of input para required and the third is the value of input para T.

The third and the fourth represent the type of input para and its value.
Similar applies to the fifth and the sixth.

Comment: Have you looked into multithreading [`apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545110/make-pandas-dataframe-apply-use-all-cores) ?

Comment: Not yet. Thanks.

Comment: Why not directly use `HAPropsSI` on the `df` numpy values? Like `df["T"].values + 273.15`... Works in my test and is a fraction faster

Comment: What does the function you are applying do and can you vectorise the operation?

Comment: If at all possible, you should rewrite `HAPropsSI` such that it directly operates on vectors of data, or dataframes, rather than on individual numbers.

Comment: Hi All, the function is from coolprop python package, so I am not sure if I can rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to vectorize your function?

I would recommend the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c) here, which explain the advantages of "fake" and "true" vectorization very well.

Comment: I tried it  and please see the error in the updated post.