# Calculate supertrend for more than 100 stocks python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-ta

I am using pandas_ta to calculate supertrend its fine for one stock but when I am trying to calculate it for like 100 stocks using a simple for loop, it takes more than 6 secs, how can I optimize it? or is there any different way to achieve it?

```
for column in close.columns:
    supertrend[column] = ta.supertrend(high=high[column], low=low[column],close=close[column], length=period, multiplier=multiplier)[props]
```

Comment: Why do you think that's a problem?  That's 60 milliseconds per stock, which is pretty good.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have seen sites like chartink.com, they calculate for more than 100 stocks in 800 milliseconds

Comment: Can you show the complete code? Using `ta.` instead of `df.ta.` and multiple dataframes to store the data seems unusual. Without further information, it's hard to say how this affects the runtime and if the loop could be avoided.

Comment: Maybe you can distribute or [parallelize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45545111/14277722) the loop with [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/)

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny here is my code
 ```high = self.give_base_value('high', inetrval, stockindex, period, offset=offset)
 low = self.give_base_value('low', inetrval, stockindex, period, offset=offset)
 close = self.give_base_value('close', inetrval, stockindex, period, offset=offset)
        for column in close.columns:
            supertrend[column] = ta.supertrend(high=high[column], low=low[column],close=close[column], length=period, multiplier=multiplier)[props]```

here high is dataframe of all the scripts with script names as columns, similarly for close and low.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I have tried dask but it seem multiprocessing is not working in python due to GIL, could you suggest any other method to achieve parallelism??