How to decrease the time calculation of multiple functions call with aggregate on pandas
i am looking for a way to reduce the time calculation of multiple functions calculations on a pandas dataframe ie i am trying to do.
It takes more than 3 minutes on my computer. Does it exist an equivalent to pandarallel with aggregate function or something equivalent to boost calculation. pandarallel does not seem to work with aggregate.
This is the code i use:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from empyrical import (cagr, 
                    annual_volatility,
                    max_drawdown,
)

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


# Exemple 
N = 10000
mu = 0.1/252
sigma = 0.15/np.sqrt(250)

# Créer un DataFrame vide pour stocker les séries temporelles
date_range = pd.date_range(start='1990-01-01', end='2020-01-01', freq='B')
# Créer un DataFrame vide avec l'index de dates
df = pd.DataFrame(index=date_range)


# Générer les séries temporelles
for i in range(N):
    series = (100+ np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(date_range)).cumsum())
    df[f"Série {i+1}"] = series

tab =  (df
        .sort_index()
        .aggregate([
            # Date de première/dernière VL
            lambda x: x.first_valid_index().date(),
            lambda x: x.last_valid_index().date(),
            # Mesure de performance 
            ## Perf total
            lambda x: 100*cagr(x[-52:].pct_change(), period='weekly') if x[-52:].isnull().sum() <= 1 else np.nan,
            lambda x: 100*cagr(x[-3*52:].pct_change(), period='weekly'),
            lambda x: 100*cagr(x[-5*52:].pct_change(), period='weekly'),
            # Mesure de risque
            # Volatilité
            lambda x: 100*annual_volatility(x[-52:].pct_change(), period='weekly'),
            lambda x: 100*annual_volatility(x[-3*52:].pct_change(), period='weekly'),
            lambda x: 100*annual_volatility(x[-5*52:].pct_change(), period='weekly'),
            ## Max DD 
            lambda x: 100*max_drawdown(x[-52:].pct_change()),
            lambda x: 100*max_drawdown(x[-3*52:].pct_change()),
            lambda x: 100*max_drawdown(x[-5*52:].pct_change()),
            ],)
        .set_axis([
            'Date de début', 'Date de fin',
            'Perf 1 an', 'Perf 3 ans', 'Perf 5 ans', 
            'Volat 1 an', 'Volat 3 ans', 'Volat 5 ans',
            'Max DD 1 an', 'Max DD 3 ans', 'Max DD 5 ans',
            ])
        .T
        .dropna()
        )

tab 



It would help understand what you are trying to do, if you provide a simple explanation of the transition you are trying to achieve,

maybe one of these libs will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545110/make-pandas-dataframe-apply-use-all-cores

You can try to use multiprocessing.Pool to process each pd.Series in separate process:
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import warnings

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from empyrical import annual_volatility, cagr, max_drawdown

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

agg_funcs = [
    # Date de première/dernière VL
    lambda x: x.first_valid_index().date(),
    lambda x: x.last_valid_index().date(),
    # Mesure de performance
    ## Perf total
    lambda x: (
        100 * cagr(x[-52:].pct_change(), period="weekly")
        if x[-52:].isnull().sum() <= 1
        else np.nan
    ),
    lambda x: 100 * cagr(x[-3 * 52 :].pct_change(), period="weekly"),
    lambda x: 100 * cagr(x[-5 * 52 :].pct_change(), period="weekly"),
    # Mesure de risque
    # Volatilité
    lambda x: 100 * annual_volatility(x[-52:].pct_change(), period="weekly"),
    lambda x: 100 * annual_volatility(x[-3 * 52 :].pct_change(), period="weekly"),
    lambda x: 100 * annual_volatility(x[-5 * 52 :].pct_change(), period="weekly"),
    ## Max DD
    lambda x: 100 * max_drawdown(x[-52:].pct_change()),
    lambda x: 100 * max_drawdown(x[-3 * 52 :].pct_change()),
    lambda x: 100 * max_drawdown(x[-5 * 52 :].pct_change()),
]

agg_labels = [
    "Date de début",
    "Date de fin",
    "Perf 1 an",
    "Perf 3 ans",
    "Perf 5 ans",
    "Volat 1 an",
    "Volat 3 ans",
    "Volat 5 ans",
    "Max DD 1 an",
    "Max DD 3 ans",
    "Max DD 5 ans",
]


def calculate_agg(series):
    name, x = series
    out = pd.Series([fn(x) for fn in agg_funcs], index=agg_labels, name=name)
    return out


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Exemple
    N = 10000
    # N = 10
    mu = 0.1 / 252
    sigma = 0.15 / np.sqrt(250)

    # Créer un DataFrame vide pour stocker les séries temporelles
    date_range = pd.date_range(start="1990-01-01", end="2020-01-01", freq="B")
    # Créer un DataFrame vide avec l'index de dates
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=date_range)

    # Générer les séries temporelles
    np.random.seed(42)
    for i in range(N):
        series = 100 + np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(date_range)).cumsum()
        df[f"Série {i+1}"] = series

    start_time = time.time()

    df_out = []
    with mp.Pool(processes=16) as pool:   # <-- adjust number of processes accordingly
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(
            calculate_agg, ((c, df[c]) for c in df.columns)
        ):
            df_out.append(result)

    df_out = pd.concat(df_out, axis=1).T

    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"--- {time.time() - start_time} seconds ---")
    print("Final shape:", df_out.shape)

Prints on my computer (AMD 5700x):
--- 5.798572540283203 seconds ---
Final shape: (10000, 11)

For comparison, original version took:
--- 39.353575229644775 seconds ---
Final shape: (10000, 11)


on my computer, it runs without ending. I don't know why ???

@Jacques Copy and paste the exact same code as I posted here. Try to adjust the processes=, set it to 1 for example, it should terminate in your original time, then increase the number.

That's what i did. I copy/paste your code and set process to 1...but it loops and never ending

@Jacques Try to generate less data, e.g. N=100, date_range from 2022 etc. Also the if __name__ == "__main__": is important

i did the same with N=10...and it loops

@Jacques How do you run the code? I run the code from standard terminal, not from notebook etc.

I use it like you (previously i run it on notebook but now i run it on regular python) and it still loops

isn't it not here that you have a problem in the line name, x = series  ???
def calculate_agg(series):
    name, x = series
    out = pd.Series([fn(x) for fn in agg_funcs], index=agg_labels, name=name)
    return out

