# Can I specify a max memory for the default dask scheduler on a shared machine?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am working on a shared analysis node at Princeton University.

I often encounter problems with my dask processes being killed due to large memory consumption. This seems to happen as a precaution from the admin side, to avoid an unstable system.

To control the resources I usually use a LocalCluster via dask.distributed, but in this particular instance this prevents me from using a numerically efficient algorithm implemented with numba (see [here for a discussion of the problem](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/3450)).

I did find an answer for specifying the amount of threads to be used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621543/how-to-specify-the-number-of-threads-processes-for-the-default-dask-scheduler), but is there a similar way to specify a maximum amount of memory for the threaded scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

No, Dask will not control the memory of the scheduler process.  If it is growing large in memory then this is a sign that you're probably misusing it a bit.  Ideally the scheduler never stores any of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I think my original question was ill-posed. I was actually looking for a way to limit the amount of memory dask occupies in total (not just the scheduler), akin to the way you can specify the worker memory in distributed. Basically, I just want to avoid that dask grabs 'all available' resources on the shared machine. I hope this is a bit clearer. I am an avid use of dask, but the internals can sometimes still confuse me, hehe.

Comment: Maybe use something like cgroups?  Dask is just a library in a Python process.  You would restrict its memory in the same way you would restrict the memory of any other native process.

Comment: Interesting. I will definitely keep that in mind. I wont be working on this machine for much longer, so I might not have the incentive to try to fix this special situation. But that might be a good solution for other folks on that machine. Ill make sure to point them to this thread. Just FYI, a lot of the problems I encountered originated in the way xarray pads missing values see g issue here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/4112). Once I realized this and wrote some logic to prevent this from happening, I encountered the memory problem much less.